# Gitlab on OS X server not displaying issue comments box

Tags: gitlab

Using the instructions [here](https://github.com/WebEntity/Installation-guide-for-GitLab-on-OS-X), I installed GitLab on a Mac server. I am able to create issues and add thumbs up/down reactions, but the text box for adding a comment does not appear. Any suggestions?

Comment: Any error message?

Comment: On the page, there is a javascript error: `t.replace is not a function. (In 't.replace(/\s+$/,"")'`

Comment: This same error is appearing in the debugger when attempting to add a comment in a commit, so it seems relevant.

Comment: In application-3cf39fb572166ba66629d97373614008.js, I have 

`return i = $(t), n = i.closest("form").find(e), "" === rstrip(NProgress, NProgress, NProgress, NProgress, NProgress, NProgress, NProgress, NProgress, NProgress, NProgress) && n.disable(), i.on("input", function() {`

whereas gitlab.com has

`return i = $(t), n = i.closest("form").find(e), "" === rstrip(i.val()) && n.disable(), i.on("input", function() {`

Comment: I don't know anything about Gitlab and probably can't help, but you should edit your question to provide those error messages and extra clarifications. It will help someone who might be able to answer your question